# Firebase duplicate value cannot be looped

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have

```
foo: { 
 a1: true,
 a2: true
}
```

when I `<div ng-repeat="(key, val) in foos">{{val}}</div>` where foos is using `angularFire()`

I return `Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Repeater: (key, val) in foos key: boolean:true`

Why it calling `true` as key and not allowed to loop?

**UPDATE**

This is the angularFire();

`angularFire(firebaseRef, $scope, 'foos');`

It only loop when they have different value.

**UPDATE 2**

I found the problem. It is a problem from angularJS 1.1.5

check out this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/gi9g1SfsuFO5j5UrBkbj?p=preview)

Comment: Can you include your initialization of `angularFire` and what your Firebase ref looks like?

Comment: @D.Hayes  sorry, my bad. It works now. Maybe I did something wrong. I'm not sure.  I'll leave this to see if the error coming out again.

Comment: @D.Hayes It is angularJS 1.1.5 problem. Check the plnkr